# check autosys job status via unix without using autorep command

Tags: shell, unix, autosys

I am trying to fetch the status of autosys job via shell script  without using autorep command.

```
I/P:
user id PID Env(AUTOSYS_JOB_NAME="test_job",script_location="/tmp/SA/test.sh")
```

From the above command I wanted to fetch the following details:

- run id
- the job success/failure/in progress everytime
- script location
- start time
- end time

when the job is running and its getting overwritten in my sql server db under following table.

I have tried

`ps aux | grep -v grep | grep 'user_id' | grep 'AUTOSYS_JOB_NAME'`

The above command is not working as expected

Comment: `*not working as expected*`, what do you get and what are you expecting that is different?  Autosys starts and monitors the jobs, so why go around it to find information that is has?  At the unix level you can see if it is running or not (process is there), name, ...  But if it is done, you have no way of knowing its status (success / failure) unless you have a dedicated log created by the script.  And runid is an autosys concept, unix has no concept of the scheduler's id numbers.